# didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer not Calling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I am trying to learn how to take and save photos using AVFoundation. I have currently been able to make a custom camera view with a button that is linked to an action to take a photo. When i click the button the delegate method is not being called.

Here is my ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var camerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoButton: UIButton!

    var captureSession : AVCaptureSession?
    var sessionOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    var photoSettings : AVCapturePhotoSettings?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        previewLayer?.frame = (self.camerView?.bounds)!
        previewLayer?.position = CGPoint(x: (self.camerView?.frame.width)! / 2, y: (self.camerView?.frame.height)!/2)

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //Capture Session 
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        let devices = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInDualCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back)

        for device in (devices?.devices)! {

            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)

                if (captureSession?.canAddInput(input))! {
                    captureSession?.addInput(input)
                }
                if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(sessionOutput))! {
                    captureSession?.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                }

                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

                previewLayer?.session = captureSession

                self.camerView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
                self.camerView.addSubview(photoButton)

                captureSession?.startRunning()

            } catch {
                print("error occurred")
            }

        }


    }

    @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {

        photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG])
        photoSettings?.flashMode = .on
        sessionOutput?.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings!, delegate: self)


    }


    //AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate Functions

    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {
        print("PhotoSampleBuffer")
    }




}
```

All i am trying to do in the didFinisheProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer method is just to print() so I know it is being called. I will figure out how to save later (unless someone can point me to a good resoure to learn this.)

Let me know if you need any other info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `capturePhoto` method (and therefore the delegate callback) is not being called because your `sessionOutput` variable is `nil`.

To fix this, instantiate the `sessionOutput` variable when it is declared:

```
var sessionOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
```

Also, you'll need to remove the `?` after the `sessionOutput` because it is no longer Optional.

```
sessionOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings!, delegate: self)
```